# Cython returns a `Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError` on `double (s.time_since_epoch().count())`

Tags: python, c++, cython

**Problem description:**
I want to access `C++` objects in Python, using `Cython`.
When running `python2 setup.py build_ext -i` I get a `Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError`

***Could you have a look below, and tell me what should I change to get Cython to compile my code?***

When I try to compile with Cython, I get:

```
$ python2 setup.py build_ext -i
Compiling ds5.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing ds5.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    cdef cppclass os_time_service:
        #double get_time() const override
        double get_time()
        #static_cast<double>(ts.time_since_epoch().count())
        double (s.time_since_epoch().count())
                                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ds5.pyx:15:37: Expected '.', found 'count'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize("ds5.pyx"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 934, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1056, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: ds5.pyx
```

The relevant lines in the `h` file are:

```
$ view backend.h
#ifndef LIBREALSENSE_BACKEND_H
#define LIBREALSENSE_BACKEND_H

#include "../include/librealsense/rs.h"     // Inherit all type definitions in the public API

#include <memory>       // For shared_ptr
#include <functional>   // For function
#include <thread>       // For this_thread::sleep_for
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <list>



const uint16_t VID_INTEL_CAMERA     = 0x8086;

namespace rsimpl
{
    namespace uvc
    {
        class time_service
        {
        public:
            virtual double get_time() const = 0;
            ~time_service() = default;
        };

        class os_time_service: public time_service
        {
        public:
            double get_time() const override
            {
                auto ts = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
                return static_cast<double>(ts.time_since_epoch().count());
            }
        };
...
```

And my pyx file is:

```
$ cat ds5.pyx
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = uvc-v4l2.cpp

cdef extern from "backend.h" namespace "rsimpl::uvc":
    #const uint16_t VID_INTEL_CAMERA     = 0x8086
    const unsigned short VID_INTEL_CAMERA     = 0x8086
    cdef cppclass time_service:
        #virtual double get_time() const = 0
        double get_time()

    cdef cppclass os_time_service:
        #double get_time() const override
        double get_time()
        #static_cast<double>(ts.time_since_epoch().count())
        double (s.time_since_epoch().count())

cdef class os_time_service_c:

    cdef os_time_service *_os_time_service_ptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self._os_time_service_ptr = new os_time_service()
        if self._os_time_service_ptr == NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self._os_time_service_ptr != NULL:
            del self._os_time_service_ptr

    cpdef double  get_time(self):
        return self._os_time_service_ptr.ts.time_since_epoch().count()
```

*Environment:*

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Python 2.7.12
Cython 0.25.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
double (s.time_since_epoch().count())
```

---

*Explanation:* Cython just needs to know that the function `double get_time()` exists - it doesn't need to know about the implementation (which is provided by your C++ code). Therefore, there's no need to try to rewrite the implementation in Cython.

---

I haven't looked at the rest of your code in much detail so there may be issues there too. A few small comments though:

In the constructor:

```
if self._os_time_service_ptr == NULL:
   raise MemoryError()
```

this is unnecessary since modern C++ raises `std::bad_alloc` if allocation fails rather than returning `NULL` (and Cython auto-converts that to `MemoryError`).

In the destructor

```
if self._os_time_service_ptr != NULL:
```

is unnecessary since it's safe to delete `NULL`. Neither of these will cause problems though.